# Cannot connect to MQTT over websocket with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, websocket, mqtt

I'm trying to connect to my mqtt host via this url: `wss://cpl-emqx-socket.staging-bitcastle.work:8083/mqtt` using [CocoaMQTT](https://github.com/emqx/CocoaMQTT) framework and create a manager class like this:

```
import CocoaMQTT

class MqttSocketManager: NSObject, CocoaMQTTDelegate {
    
    
    static let shared = MqttSocketManager()
    
    var mqtt: CocoaMQTT!
    
    func start() {
        let websocket = CocoaMQTTWebSocket(uri: "/mqtt")
        let clientID = "CocoaMQTT-" + String(ProcessInfo().processIdentifier)
        mqtt = CocoaMQTT(clientID: clientID, host: "cpl-emqx-socket.staging-bitcastle.work", port: 8083, socket: websocket)
        mqtt.keepAlive = 60
        mqtt.enableSSL = true
        mqtt.allowUntrustCACertificate = true
        _ = mqtt.connect()
        mqtt.logLevel = .debug
    }
        
    func mqtt(_ mqtt: CocoaMQTT, didConnectAck ack: CocoaMQTTConnAck) {
        if ack == .accept {
            mqtt.subscribe("orderbook_BTC_USDT")
        }
        print("Mqtt: DidConnect")
    }
    
    func mqtt(_ mqtt: CocoaMQTT, didPublishMessage message: CocoaMQTTMessage, id: UInt16) {
        print("Mqtt: didPublishMessage")
    }
    
    func mqtt(_ mqtt: CocoaMQTT, didPublishAck id: UInt16) {
        print("Mqtt: didPublishAck")
    }
    
    func mqtt(_ mqtt: CocoaMQTT, didReceiveMessage message: CocoaMQTTMessage, id: UInt16) {
        print("Mqtt: didReceiveMessage")
    }
    
    func mqtt(_ mqtt: CocoaMQTT, didSubscribeTopics success: NSDictionary, failed: [String]) {
        print("Mqtt: didSubscribeTopics")
    }
    
    func mqtt(_ mqtt: CocoaMQTT, didUnsubscribeTopics topics: [String]) {
        print("Mqtt: didUnsubscribeTopics")
    }
    
    func mqttDidDisconnect(_ mqtt: CocoaMQTT, withError err: Error?) {
        print("Mqtt: mqttDidDisconnect")    }
    
    func mqttDidPing(_ mqtt: CocoaMQTT) {
        print("Mqtt: mqttDidPing")
    }
    
    func mqttDidReceivePong(_ mqtt: CocoaMQTT) {
        print("Mqtt: mqttDidReceivePong")
    }
}
```

Then in AppDelegate `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`:

`MqttSocketManager.shared.start()`

But when put a breakpoint to function `didConnectAck` and `didReceiveMessage` there is nothing happened. They aren't called. Can someone point me to what's wrong with my code? I'm stuck with it for 3 days.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your `CocoaMQTTDelegate` delegate. Add `mqtt.delegate = self` in `start()` just before `_ = mqtt.connect()`

Comment: I tried. But the console print this log: `CocoaMQTT(debug): Call the SSL/TLS manually validating function`